# If file does not exist create a dataframe instead

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to be able to check if a CSV file exists in my directory.  If it does not, I want to create an empty dataframe with certain columns.  If it does I simply want to load that file.  The problem is the code reads the else statement and triggers the error of file not found.

```
if path.exists('raw.csv') == False:
    columns = ['join','fund_type','line_type','actual_amount','period','org']
    revenueMain = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
elif path.exists('raw.csv') == True:
    revenueMain = pd.read_csv('rev.csv', header=0)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you have the logic wrong.  There is no need for an `elif` after the it fails the first `if`

```
import os.path as path

if path.exists('raw.csv'):
   revenueMain = pd.read_csv('rev.csv', header=0)
else:
   columns = ['join','fund_type','line_type','actual_amount','period','org']
   revenueMain = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
```

You could also catch the error using:

```
try:
   revenueMain = pd.read_csv('rev.csv', header=0)
except:
   columns = ['join','fund_type','line_type','actual_amount','period','org']
   revenueMain = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
```

Comment: That won't work.  Let me try to explain my logic.  I'm loading either a CSV file or a newly created dataframe in the variable revenueMain.  If the file does exist, I'll get a print statement stating true.  But I still haven't loaded it.  So somewhere in my script I'll have to write: revenueMain = pd.read_csv('rev.csv', header=0).  As long as that file exists there's no problem, but if it doesn't, it will trigger an error at that point irrespective of my prior conditional.

Comment: @huesecon edited my post with your required `pd.read_csv`.  I had `print(True)` for testing on my computer.

Comment: @huesecon if neither of those work, I would double check your working directory to make sure you are in the right place :)